# How to capture output in Java

Tags: java, arrays, output

well i got my code here

```
static void snake(String u[][]){
        for(int i=0; i<u.length; i++){
            if(i%2==0){
                for(int j=0; j<u[i].length; j++){
                    String asli = u[i][j];
                    System.out.print(asli+"");
                }
            }else
                for(int j=u[i].length-1; j>=0; j--){
                    String asli = u[i][j];
                    System.out.print(asli+"");

                }
            }


        }
```

my code up there is to read an array that i create before. and it will read the array in snake path from right to left, then in the next row it will read from left to right, and so on.

i will call this method in my code like this :

```
snake(matrix);
```

so the array that i create before will be proceed in to this method.

it will create an output like "asdbasdbasdbsad" and i want to capture that...
i have try printstream but it's didn't work.
that output, i need them to be proceed in my another code. and i can't get them right. 
is it any method instead first save them into a file then read the file in the next method?
is it any different logical method that can applied to make something like that? 
or is it possible to convert array like my code up there to a string? 
sorry for my English, English is not my native language. i will appreciate any help, and thanks before..

i use the code from npinti, and it's work.

```
static String ular(String u[][]){
        StringBuilder code2 = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i=0; i<u.length; i++){
            if(i%2==0){
                for(int j=0; j<u[i].length; j++){
                    String asli = u[i][j];
                    System.out.print(asli+"");
                    code2.append(asli);
                    //System.out.print(asli+"");

                }
            }else
                for(int j=u[i].length-1; j>=0; j--){
                    String asli = u[i][j];
                    System.out.print(asli+"");
                    code2.append(asli);
                    //System.out.print(asli+"");

                }
            }
        return code2.toString();


    }
```

Comment: "i need them to be proceed in my another code" and " is it any method instead first save them into a file then read the file in the next method?" you have it already in asli String , so you can use a return or load it in a class attribute, so it will be visible for the rest of others members in your class, is it what you what?

Comment: System.setOut(outStream);

Comment: well, thank you to you 2. i already got it. thank you for your concern. pardon me for my english, it's not my native language..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do would be to make your method `return` whatever it prints in the form of a `String` or some `Collection`.

For instance, you could do this:

```
static String snake(String u[][]){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<u.length; i++){
        if(i%2==0){
            for(int j=0; j<u[i].length; j++){
                String asli = u[i][j];
                System.out.print(asli+"");
                sb.append(asli + ",");
            }
        }else
            for(int j=u[i].length-1; j>=0; j--){
                String asli = u[i][j];
                System.out.print(asli+"");
                sb.append(asli + ",");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

This should return a comma delimited `String` which you can later use in your program like so:

```
String[][] u = ...
String result = snake(u);
```

EDIT: This is another way you can go at it:

```
static List<String> snake(String u[][]){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0; i<u.length; i++){
        if(i%2==0){
            for(int j=0; j<u[i].length; j++){
                String asli = u[i][j];
                System.out.print(asli+"");
                list.add(asli);
            }
        }else
            for(int j=u[i].length-1; j>=0; j--){
                String asli = u[i][j];
                System.out.print(asli+"");
                list.add(asli);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

And you call it like so:

```
String[][] u = ...
List<String> moves = snake(u);
```

Comment: thanks for your concern.. i will try both the code that you apply. i will post here if it works. Thank you so much..

Comment: well, thank you so much, npinti. it really works. i'm using your 1st method, and that's it. again, thank you..

Comment: @rizal: Glad it worked. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it so. This will show on your statistics which in turn will motivate other users to answer any other questions you might have in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing the result, return it;

```
static String snake(String u[][]) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            for(int j = 0; j < u[i].length; j++) {
                String asli = u[i][j];
                builder.append(asli);
            }
        }
        else
            for (int j = u[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                String asli = u[i][j];
                builder.append(asli);
            }
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: don't forget the change in the method signature ;)

Comment: Just noticed that and fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: thanks. i will try either of the code you post here. i'll try later, and thanks again for your concern